# Foreign key: in which table?

Tags: foreign-key, table

I made the tables **blood_types** and **persons**. Should the foreign key  be created in the **blood_types** or in the **persons** table like I did?

A person can have **1** blood type. A blood type can be assigned to **multiple** persons.

```
CREATE TABLE blood_types
(
 blo_id serial NOT NULL,
 blo_name character varying(10),
 CONSTRAINT blood_types_pkey PRIMARY KEY (blo_id)
)

CREATE TABLE persons
(
  per_id serial NOT NULL,
  per_passport character varying(50),
  per_name character varying(50),
  per_blood_type integer, 
  CONSTRAINT persons_pkey PRIMARY KEY (per_id),
  CONSTRAINT persons_per_blood_type_fkey FOREIGN KEY (per_blood_type)
      REFERENCES per_blood_types (blo_id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

Or maybe should the foreign key be created in the blood_type table?
I have more similars and simples examples but I can't understand.
Should I think as **weak** and **strong** entities (I think both are strong) or maybe having in mind the **cardinalities**?

Comment: This is the correct way of modeling it.

Answer (score 0):

In your `blood_types` table,

```
CREATE TABLE blood_types
(
 blo_id serial NOT NULL,
 blo_name character varying(10),
 CONSTRAINT blood_types_pkey PRIMARY KEY (blo_id)
)
```

You correctly have blo_id as a `PRIMARY KEY`.

And then in the `persons` table, have the `per_blood_type` integer as a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing `blo_id` in table `blood_types` (as you appear to have - can't check exact syntax - don't have running PostgreSQL system at the minute). The way you have have it appears to be the correct way - blood type depends on the person and only the person - not the other way round.